# Find Jira issues recently assigned to me

Tags: jira

The trick is the "recently assigned" part.

The recently updated widget is insufficient because we're churning through a fair number of issues each day. Items recently assigned to me get lost in the items I've recently updated myself.

I'm thinking it would be something like:
  assignee=currentUser() AND (assignee!=currentUser() -3d).

It's the !currentuser() three days ago I can't figure out how to do

I've done a bit of research and understand I can do relative times. 
What I cannot figure out is how to determine who the currentUser was 3 days ago.

I'm running Jira 6.2.

--ray

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Assignee was not in (Scott) before "-3d" and assignee=Scott
```

This is not perfect though; although it answers your direct question, this overall logic misses issues that were previously assigned to you, assigned away to someone else, and then assigned back recently.

You can use the "[by](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=179442050#AdvancedSearching-WASIN)" predicate to filter based on who did the assign, but there is no immediately obvious way to implement "not by" logic. (Perhaps this suggests that there may be a better overall way to do what you're doing, by potentially changing your method of working with issues?)

Comment: The 'not in' and 'before' helped greatly. 
I ended up creating a filter as follows:
Assignee was not in (currentUser()) before "-1h" and assignee=currentUser() AND status not in (closed)

Helps to show me things that have very recently been assigned to me. Granted, it will miss items that I owned less than an hour ago -- but from a practical point of view this is useful.